# I'm trying to trigger an event on my main form, when a child form's child form gets closed

Tags: c#

From a button on my main form, I open up a search form. When I click on a button on my search form, it opens up a new form which shows the search results.

When I click a button on my "search results" form, I want it to trigger an event in my main form.

I've tried the code below but it didn't work, basically it did nothing.

Main Form:

```
public void mainBtnMenuSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmSearch frmSearch = new frmSearch();                    // My search form
            frmSearchList frmSearchList = new frmSearchList();        // My search results form
            frmSearchList.FormClosed += frmSearchTriggerEvent;        // Search results form closed

            frmSearch.Show();
        }


public void frmSearchTriggerEvent(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (frmSearchList.isOpenedProject == true)
            {
                loadForm();               // Load another form into the panel in my Main form
            }
            else if (frmSearchList.isOpenedProject == false)
            {
                // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            }
        }
```

Search Form:

```
public void searchByDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // some code for passing search results

            frmSearchList frmSearchList = new frmSearchList();        // My search results form
            frmSearchList.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
```

Search Results Form:

```
public void openProjectByResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // some code for passing selected result's details

            this.Close();
        }
```

**EDIT**
I've checked with breakpoints. `frmSearchTriggerEvent` isn't getting triggered, and `frmSearchList.isOpenedProject` gets true before the trigger.

Comment: So are you saying `frmSearchTriggerEvent` is never triggered? did you put a *break point* there to make sure ?

Comment: Maybe, `frmSearchList.isOpenedProject` is false, which would lead to no observable behaviour. Did you verify with a breakpoint that `frmSearchTriggerEvent` is not called?

Comment: @TheGeneral; yes I've put a break point. `frmSearchTriggerEvent` is not triggering.

@SomeBody; I also checked `frmSearchList.isOpenedProject` is getting true, I've verified with a breakpoint.

Comment: Problem solved, and I've probably found the cause of it. Check the answer.

Comment: But.. the code as posted doesn't seem to implement the requirement. You said "form A opens form B, form B opens form C and I want form A to do something when form C closes" - the posted code attaches an event handler to form B's closing ?

Comment: @CaiusJard form B is `frmSearch`. form C is `frmSearchList`. I've tried to attach the event handler to form C, which is `frmSearchList`.

Comment: Yep, I see it now. Perhaps take it as feedback on your code's "glanceability" - it doesn't use common C# conventions and uses very similar names for classes and variables so it's not easy to grok quickly  - so yes, I agree with your surmising; there isn't anything in the code that connects the SearchForm you make(and show) to the SearchResultListForm that you make (and never show)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've found out what the problem is.

Both in the Main and Search forms, I've declared the `frmSearchList` as a new form, which means it's declared as a new form *twice*.

I've declared `frmSearchList` form once in a global class (which I'm also using for the variables that working on SQL queries), linked the FormClosed event and form.Show() command to that. Now it works.

Comment: *a global class* - sounds horrific! 

Comment: *it's declared as a new form twice* - if you named your local variables `likeThis` and your class level variables `_likeThis`, that situation probably wouldn't happen

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm new to C# actually, still learning by trial and error. I'll be careful about that in the future, thanks for the advice.